# Authorization header using Alamofire

Tags: ios, alamofire

I'm working with an API which puts an authorization key in the header, it works fine in Postman:

[image: Postman snippet]

And it's my code:

```
let url = Requests.listCities(withLanguage: .en)
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [ "Authorization": "pmJAdo5N26WW74kCEy6RRvIdCScFCbAtKc2o0FNy"]
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .validate(contentType: [MIMEType.JSON])
            .responseJSON {response in
                completion(response)
        }
```

The response is:

```
SUCCESS: {
    error = Unauthorized;
    status = failed;
}
```

Am I doing it wrong or is the `Authorization` omitted during the request?

This is the request debug:

```
$ curl -v \
    -H "Accept-Language: en;q=1.0, ar-US;q=0.9" \
    -H "Authorization: pmJAdo5N26WW74kCEy6RRvIdCScFCbAtKc2o0FNy" \
    -H "User-Agent: skinup/1.0 (appname; build:1; iOS 10.3.1) Alamofire/4.5.0" \
    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5"
```

Comment: Are you sure working with the same URL on both postman and the app?

Comment: What if you use JSONEncoding.default instead of URLEncoding.default and remove the .validate(contentType: [MIMEType.JSON]) line?

Comment: You doing it exactly according to Alamofire's example, so you should be fine. I would debug actual HTTP traffic either on server, or local proxy – this quickly resolves issues like this.

Comment: can you please post the URL so I can check with real one

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ Sorry cannot share the key.

Comment: can you please try with this way let headers = [
            "Authorization": "pmJAdo5N26WW74kCEy6RRvIdCScFCbAtKc2o0FNy",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ I have tried it before

Comment: It was all about an "/" at the end of the URL!!

Comment: @Maysam thats why I ask you about URL man ;)

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ I didn't notice that bloody slash

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Alamofire's headers into an URLRequest. So you can do this:

```
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "your URL")!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue
    urlRequest = try! URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: nil)
    urlRequest.setValue("pmJAdo5N26WW74kCEy6RRvIdCScFCbAtKc2o0FNy", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in

        //code below
        completion(response)
    })
```

Maybe It would solve your problem ;)