# JWT Authentication with Alamofire download function

Tags: ios, swift, jwt, alamofire, express-jwt

I'm trying to download a zip file and save it from server using JWT token authentication thanks to [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). The download works well without token authentication, the file is saved with success. When I activate the server-side authentication (using Passport.js with NodeJS), I always received 401. I attach the token to the header with the sessionManager adapter function. Others request (post, get using sessionManager.request(..) ) works well with this authentication mechanism.

Question is : Can we modify the header of Alamofire download function ? If yes how ?

Any advices appreciated

```
func getZip(){

    let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    let authHandler = JWTAccessTokenAdapter(accessToken: Auth.getAccessToken())

    sessionManager.retrier = authHandler
    sessionManager.adapter = authHandler


    let downloadUrl: String = Auth.getApiEndpoint() + "get_zip"
    let destinationPath: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0];
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("myZip.zip")
        return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }


    sessionManager.download(downloadUrl, method: .get,  encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, to: destinationPath)
        .downloadProgress { progress in
            print(">> Zip Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        }
        .responseData { response in
            switch response.result{
            case .success:
                if response.destinationURL != nil, let filePath = response.destinationURL?.absoluteString {
                    print("success & filepath : \(filePath)")
                    completionHandler(filePath, true)
                }
                break
            case .failure:
                print("faillure")
                completionHandler("", false)
                break
            }

        }
    } 
}
```

**JWT Adapter :**

```
class JWTAccessTokenAdapter: RequestAdapter {

     typealias JWT = String
     private var accessToken: JWT

     func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest

        if let urlString = urlRequest.url?.absoluteString, urlString.hasPrefix(Auth.getApiEndpoint()) {
        /// Set the Authorization header value using the access token.
           urlRequest.setValue(accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        }

    return urlRequest

   }
}
```

Output :

```
response: SUCCESS: 12 bytes // (Unauthorized) -> Corrupted zip file
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44910222/4311935 Use same for download

Comment: @canister_exister thank you for the link. This is the same behavior as the RequestAdapter function. I implemented the solution from the link and the result is unfortunately the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a `validation` step in your request chain, all responses will be considered successful. So check your response code (or just add `.validate()` before `responseData`) and see if your request is actually successful. Also, you may want to double check your parameter encoding, though you don't seem to be sending any parameters.

Comment: I was missing the validation step, this is working now thank you. I don't need parameters, the authentication is made in the header and I don't need more informations to send. Should I specify the parameter encoding although I don't send parameters ?